# ERROR:NgdBuild:605 - logical root block 'entity_name' with type 'entity_name' is unexpanded

Tags: vhdl

First of all, I'm a newbie to vhdl, and I wrote the following code, which I want to implement as the starting point of the project, from the main module of the project and then simulate:

```
entity main is
--empty entity  
end main;

architecture Behavioral of main is
    signal clk : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal zero : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0000";
    
    type Bitonic_Sequence is array (0 to 7) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    signal B_S : Bitonic_Sequence := ("0001" , "0011" , "0011" , "0100" , "1000" , "0110" , "0010" , "0000");
    
    component PROC is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC := '0';
           proc_d_in : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
           near_proc_d_in : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
           proc_d_out : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0));
    end component PROC;
    
begin
    p_clk : process
    begin
        clk <= '0';
        --wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= '1';
        --wait for 10 ns;
    end process p_clk;
    
    Hypercube_Processors: 
   for I in 0 to 7 generate
      PROCX : PROC port map(clk , B_S(I), zero , zero);
   end generate Hypercube_Processors;
    
end Behavioral;
```

the body of the main entity is empty, because it has no input and output, and a series of signals are defined in its architecture that Applies to its components.
But after clicking 'implement Top Module', I get the following error:

> ERROR:NgdBuild:605 - logical root block 'main' with type 'main' is
> unexpanded.    Symbol 'main' is not supported in target 'spartan3e'.

In fact, I do not know where VHDL projects start.
For example, in other languages, the main function is the starting point of the program.

Comment: Vhdl has no `main` because vhdl is not a programming language.  It is a hardware description language. Code for an fpga requires a pinout. With no external connectivity,  the design effectively does nothing,  so all logic is removed.  In your code your `clk`is also a problem.  A clock is usually provided via an fpga pin.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some basic orientation.

While the top level (which will be a testbench rather than a main program) needs no I/O ports, that means it can only be simulated, not "Implemented". The purpose of such a top level is to instantiate an actual processing module (or more than one) like your PROC, stimulate them with test signals, and check their outputs.

"Implement"ing this top level module makes no sense, since there is no way to get data into it or results out from it, since there are no I/O ports! ("Synthesise" first, then "Implement" may be different steps, depending on the toolchain).

So the only way to use it is to "simulate" it (via "behavioural simulation"). This is slow, but allows accurate and detailed observation of the innards, to allow you to get the PROC design working correctly. There is nothing *wrong* in calling this testbench "main", but it's unusual...

Then (i.e. once PROC is tested and working) it is PROC that you will "implement", and the result will be a chip design with all the input and output pins you defined, as the I/O you need.

Given this "main" you would also need a PCB laid out to accommodate 8 separate "PROC" FPGAs, which is probably not what you want for a first project...

---

Instead you probably want to create your 8 PROC array on a single (fairly large) FPGA, which for a first project, you will buy on some PCB with standard interfaces such as Ethernet or USB, or PCIe to plug into a host computer. I'll assume Ethernet, so you can simply connect to this board by cable.

In the FPGA, you will then "implement" a toplevel design which has your 8 PROC modules, and a system connecting them to that Ethernet interface. It will obviously have I/O pins for that Ethernet and other I/Os (some status LEDs or other monitoring signals are useful, possibly an UART), and it is this toplevel design that you will instantiate in your portless "main" (testbench).

It's quite common for the interconnection system to involve an ARM CPU and Ethernet interface as standard components (see Xilinx Zynq FPGAs for example,  and this can even run a basic Linux distro (Yocto). Then the connection to your PROC array would be via the ARM AXI bus, also available as a standard component.

Setting up all this system level I/O stuff (simply learning the toolchain and how the standard blocks plug together) can be a project in itself, though there are lots of tutorials - and interfacing your core to AXI bus is another significant task.

So an outline workflow might be:

1. Instantiate a SINGLE "PROC" core in a testbench and simulate it to verify it does exactly what you want. Don't underestimate the power of small, fast simulations and don't bog down simulating all of them at once! That'll need a VERY powerful machine.
2. Create an entity containing a (probably smaller, ideally generic sized) PROC array and whatever you need to interact with them over AXI bus. Then (a) "Implement" this and see how much FPGA resource you need for it; this will determine the size and price of the FPGA you need. And (b) instantiate it in a testbench to verify you can communicate  with your PROCs via AXI. (But you don't have to re-verify everything you did at 1).
3. Create a top level system (ARM CPU, Ethernet etc, possibly DDR memory) using standard blocks and verify you can get data in and out via Ethernet, as a standalone project. This will probably be done via "implement" and tested on your FPGA board; simulation is likely to be awkward and painfully slow.
4. Add your AXI core with your custom processor to this toplevel system. "Implement" and test.
5. For any bugs in either "PROC" or the array, it is probably easiest to go back to the testbench in (1) or (2) and extend it to catch the bug, then verify the fix by simulation, then recreate the higher levels.

The above assumes you want to get to the stage of using your processor array in anger; if this is for class credit, steps 1,2 may be sufficient to prove the point.